# how to implement airflow DAG in a loop

Tags: python, airflow

I just started with Airflow. I want to set up a DAG in a loop, where the next DAG starts when the previous DAG is completed. Here is the work flow that I want to achieve:

```
list_of_files = [......]
for file in list_of_files:
   dag = DAG('pipeline', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None)
   t1 = BashOperator('copy_this_file', ....)
   t2 = BashOperator('process_this_file', ...)
   t1.set_downstream(t2)
```

If I run `airflow backfill pipeline -s 2019-05-01`, all the DAGs are started simultaneously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DAGs can't depend on each other, they are separate workflows. You want to configure tasks to depend on each other instead. You can have a single DAG with multiple execution branches, one for each file, something like this (not tested):

```py
dag = DAG('pipeline', ...)
list_of_files = [......]
with dag:
    for file in list_of_files:
       t1 = BashOperator('copy_this_file', ....)
       t2 = BashOperator('process_this_file', ...)
       t1.set_downstream(t2)
```